# Java Bitshift to Replace Math.pow

Tags: java, math, pow

I need to replace a Math.pow in Java with bitshift.

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    Math.pow(16, n - i - 1)
```

Where n is the length of a hex number.
13304fb would mean n= 7.
It's basically converting hex to decimal.

Now I need to replace that Math.pow with Bitshift. I cant figure it out, because the n could be as large as it wants to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `16^(n - i -1)` = `2^(4 * (n - i -1))`
2. `2^x` = `1 << x.`

Therefore: `16^(n-i-1)` = `1 << (4 * (n -i -1))`

(Using the `^` symbol to mean "to the power of", not XOR)

Comment: Ah! I was trying to look at it like 16 ^ x = 1 << x, but I never considered having to drop the 16 down because << is like multiply by powers of 2.
Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

More generic way:

```
public static double posIntPow(final double pVal, final int pPow) {
    double ret = 1;
    double v1, v2;
    int n = pPow;
    v1 = pVal;
    if ((n & 1) == 1) {
        ret = pVal;
    }
    n = n >>> 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        v2 = v1 * v1;
        if ((n & 1) == 1) {
            ret = ret * v2;
        }
        v1 = v2;
        n = n >>> 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```